# Silverlight: StreamReader works slowly for browser cache

Tags: silverlight, caching, locking, streamreader

In SL4 application I perform a lot of requests (30) to the server in the same time (+~3 sec) by using HttpWebRequest. As a result I receive the same count of responses and start to process streams

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult)
using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var str = stream.ReadToEnd();
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
}
```

1. All responsies are received (server returned 304 - not modified)
2. For each response program creates new thread (because of asynchronusResult).
3. When I try to fetch data from stream it takes a lot of time when stream.ReadToEnd() method works. I don't now what inside ReadToEnd() but it seems that stream reading performs in one thread or any locking occurs. Any ideas??
   Why it happes? Everything incapsulated in separate threads and works fast except this method.

Comment: I/O is always the slow part of a program.  Using multiple threads doesn't help, your machine still only have one TCP/IP driver stack and one network card.  Or disk if this comes from cache.  And yes, there are locks built in the OS code that serializes access to those shared resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are using the browser http stack, in which case your browser will almost certainly have a limit on the number of connections you can make to a given subdomain at once- in many browser this is two.

A common trick, is to [use multiple sub domains](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-subdomains.html) to serve content.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it did not help. I localized problem and found that stream reader slows only when response comes from browser cache (not from server)